# Creating an app similar to the energy bar app

Tags: pycharm, spyder

I would like to create an application which is similar to the Energy bar application. I would like create this application using python. Any idead on how i should start. Where i should start from. Or what and what do i need to create this app.

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and review your question.